# Is a memory upgrade a viable option to fix performance issues?

Tags: windows-xp, memory, upgrade

I'm currently seeing my PC getting bogged down by Firefox 11.0 **alone** with *only* one hundred tabs open.

Resulting in a memory use of over 530M , VM size of over 800M and an insane amount of page faults (easily reaching 100 **million** over the course of the day). The PF delta during normal operation easily reaches 7k with peaks to 15k sometimes reaching over 20k.

This leads to a (real) deterioration to response time when switching, opening and closing tabs, opening menus, typing, ...

My question is: Am I right in assuming that plugging in more RAM (either adding 2x1GB or replacing the existing RAM with 2x2GB or 4x1GB) will solve this problem?

My specs:

- Windows XP Home Edition SP3 (32 bit)
- Intel Core Duo 2,4 GHz
- 2x512MB RAM 800MHz DDR2 (dual channel)
- 4MB unified cache
- 320GB HDD
- Intel G33 (X3100) onboard graphics (no graphics card but PCI express x16 slot is available)

Comment: From SU's faq: "[This site] is not about ... shopping or buying recommendation[s]".

Comment: @DanielAndersson I altered the nuance of the question to just "will X solve my problem"

Comment: @studiohack I altered the nuance of the question to just "will X solve my problem"

Comment: With only 100 tabs open? Are you serious? What is your expectation with only 1 gig of RAM?

Comment: @Kyle not as severe a slowdown as I experience now

Comment: 100 tabs!!! Ever heard of bookmarks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the plunge and upgraded my memory  with an additional 2 gigs

and it solved my problem

Comment: Memory is the right thing, as you found out. FF with 100 tabs can never be used with the term "only" except in jest. FF is a memory hog even without 100 tabs, and trying to run even just plain ol' XP with only 1GB of RAM is asking for trouble. 2GB is the minimum that XP will run well on, just the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not... me upgrading my workstation to an SSD has done miracles.

Furthermore, /Apps -> SSD /home -> spinner :)  (Not sure if you can do the same on windows)

However, to answer your particular question....   use the SSD as a swap drive :))))))))  you have too many tabs open for the class of machine you're on :)

Hope this helps